# Internal logic, real number objects

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

Is the following true?

- In a category whose internal logic **does not** support the law of excluded middle, the Dedekind real object can be proven **externally** to be nonisomorphic to the Cauchy real.

Can you show me such proof and/or explain to me why is that the internal logic being weaker serves as an obstruction to the existence of an isomorphism in a stronger logic?

I'll be extra happy if someone can explain to me the significance and "usage" of internal logic.

---

Actually, can I think about it this way: when one proves something, say the nonequivalence above, using an external logic, say the classical one, what one's actually doing is imposing a particular set-theoretic model to the theory of Dedekind and Cauchy reals, thus breaking some kind of "atomicity"/"model agnosticity"(?), and drawing a conclusion which is only true in the set-theoretic models? I.e. one of the advantages of the internal logics is "model agnosticity"?

Comment: There is some confusion here over "in a category". The correct statement is "there exists at least one category in which (etc.)".

Answer (score 1):

This is emphatically *not* true. If we work constructively, we merely require the following choice principle: for all $f : 2 \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, if $f$ is surjective, then there exists $g : \mathbb{N} \to 2 \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $f \circ g = 1_\mathbb{N}$. This choice principle is a very weak form of countable choice and is implied by the law of excluded middle.

So we could, for instance, take any model of $ZF + \neg AC$ (which is dramatic overkill). In this model, the Cauchy and Dedekind reals would coincide.

Edit: presheaf toposes satisfy countable choice, so in any presheaf topos (including those that don’t support excluded middle - that is, all presheaves over any non-groupoid category), the Dedekind and Cauchy reals coincide. So the fact that LEM fails does not necessarily mean that the Dedekind and Cauchy reals don’t coincide.

Comment: Okay thanks. Question edited. Also any comment on the paragraph below the line?

Comment: @SayakoHoshimiya I don't really understand what your question below the line is. It is quite vague, especially since we cannot prove the thing whose proof you are using as an example.

Comment: you mean there's no category in which the two reals are nonisomorphic?

Comment: @SayakoHoshimiya If you're asking for a category in which Cauchy and Dedekind reals are nonisomorphic, it is completely mysterious how that question could have been found in what you wrote below the line.

Comment: @SayakoHoshimiya No, I do not mean that. $Sh(\mathbb{R})$ is a simple example of a topos where the Dedekind and Cauchy reals are distinct. The Dedekind reals are the sheaf of continuous functions to $\mathbb{R}$, while the Cauchy reals are the sheaf of locally constant functions to $\mathbb{R}$.